# Second structural equations in lorentzian space $\Bbb L^3$.

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, differential-forms, semi-riemannian-geometry

I'm rewriting O'Neill's "Elementary Differential Geometry"'s section on connection forms in Lorentz-Minkowski space $\Bbb L^3$, and I'm having trouble proving the second structural equations $${\rm d}\omega_{ij} = \sum_k \omega_{ik} \wedge \omega_{\color{blue}{kj}}.$$
I'm using the signature $(+,+,-)$, that is, $$G = \begin{pmatrix} 1& 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  & -1\end{pmatrix}.$$ I know for a fact that this result is true, I've seen it in a more general form in his other book, "The Geometry of Kerr Black Holes". The proof there is overkill for what I'm doing here. Since these sign conventions are such a pain, I'll put the definitions I'm working with here, along with two useful results that I've proved:

> **Definition:** Given a frame field $\{{\bf E}_i\}_{i = 1}^3$, the $1$-forms defined by $$\omega_{ij}({\bf V}) = \epsilon_j \langle
>  \nabla_{\bf V}{\bf E}_i, {\bf E}_j \rangle$$ are called the connection
>    forms of the given frame field. Also, $\omega_{ij} = -\epsilon_i
>  \epsilon_j \omega_{ji}$, where $\epsilon_i = \langle {\bf E}_i,{\bf
>  E}_i\rangle$.
>
> **Definition:** Given a matrix $A = (a_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j \leq 3}$, where the $a_{ij}$ are functions, we define ${\rm d}A = ({\rm
>  d}a_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j \leq 3}$ and $A_\epsilon = (\epsilon_i
>  a_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j \leq 3}$.
>
> **Theorem:** Let $\{{\bf E}_i\}_{i = 1}^3$ be a frame field, and $A = (a_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j\leq 3}$ be its attitude matrix, that is, ${\bf E}_i = \sum_j a_{ij} \partial_j$. If $\omega = (\omega_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j \leq 3}$, then $$\omega = {\rm d}A \cdot GA_\epsilon^{ \ t},$$ where the product in
>    the right side is to be seen as the wedge product. Note: $A_\epsilon^{
>  \ t} \neq A_{\ \epsilon}^t$.
>
> **Lemma:** With notation as above: $$A \cdot GA_{\epsilon}^{\ t} = {\rm Id_3}.$$

With this I can go on. I have: $$\begin{align}\omega &=  {\rm d}A \cdot GA_\epsilon^{ \ t} \\ &\implies {\rm d}\omega = {\rm d}( {\rm d}A \cdot GA_\epsilon^{ \ t}) \\ &\implies {\rm d}\omega = -  {\rm d}A\cdot {\rm d}(GA_\epsilon^{\ t})  \\ &\implies {\rm d}\omega = - {\rm d}A \cdot G ({\rm d}A)_\epsilon^{\ t} \\ &\implies{\rm d}\omega = -{\rm d}A \cdot GA_{\epsilon}^{\ t} \cdot A \cdot G^t({\rm d}A)_\epsilon^{\ t} \\ &\implies {\rm d}\omega = -\omega \cdot ({\rm d}A)_\epsilon G A^t\end{align}.$$

Since I don't know how to go from here, I'll open both sides. Brace yourself, it'll be ugly.

$$\begin{align} {\rm d}\omega_{ij} &= -\sum_k \omega_{ik} \wedge (({\rm d}A)_\epsilon G A^t)_{kj}\\ &= -\sum_k \omega_{ik} \wedge \left(\sum_l \epsilon_k {\rm d}a_{kl}(GA^t)_{lj}\right) \\ &= -\sum_k \epsilon_k\omega_{ik} \wedge \left(\sum_l {\rm d}a_{kl} (g_{l1}a_{j1} + g_{l2}a_{j2}+g_{l3}a_{j3})\right) \\  &= -\sum_k \epsilon_k \omega_{ik } \wedge ({\rm d}a_{k1}a_{j1}+{\rm d}a_{k2}a_{j2} - {\rm d}a_{k3}a_{j3}) \\ &= \sum_{k} \omega_{ik} \wedge (-\epsilon_k \epsilon_j \omega_{kj}) \\ &= \sum_k \omega_{ik} \wedge \omega_{\color{red}{jk}}\end{align}.$$

The indices are swapped in this last $\omega$ and I can't find the mistake. Please help.

Comment: Maybe I should post this on MO? I never know if the level of the question is high enough for their standards. I'll wait a few days, anyway.

Comment: maybe you should want check this http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~benchow/250-12-03.pdf

Comment: there is a version for the definition of the connection forms which it reads as $$\nabla_XE_k=\sum_s{\omega^s}_k(X)E_s$$

Comment: Yes, but that definition is not the same as the one I'm using for this problem. And for this question, I want only to solve the *specific* problem of these indices. I have no idea what's wrong. And I'm too close of the result to give up on it and go for another approach.

Comment: isn't that the connection forms are unique?

Comment: Compare the definitions of the connection forms given in "Elementary Differential Geometry" and in "The Geometry of Kerr Black Holes". Pay close attention to the indices. The definitions doesn't agree. The structural equations in the second book appear with a sign that is missing in the first book.

Comment: whatever, but  with the implicit definition $\nabla_X(E_k)={\omega^s}_k(X)E_s$, one gets $\langle\nabla_X(E_k),E_t\rangle=\sum_s{\omega^s}_k(X)\eta_{st}$, being $\eta_{st}$ the Lorentzian pseudo-metric.